# Hi anyone? Go here a little bit

Tags: bots, telegram

I'm having problem in my telegram bot with this code

```php
<?php

    if ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] != "on") {
        $url = "https://". $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        header("Location: $url");
        exit;
    }

    $botToken = "XXXX...";
    $website = "https://api.telegram.org/bot".$botToken;

    $content = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $update = json_decode($content, true);
    $chatId = $update["message"]["chat"]["id"];
    $message = $update["message"]["text"];
    // get message_id
    $messageId = $update["message"]["message_id"];
    switch($message) {
        case("action"):
            sendMessage($chatId, "What should I do?");
            break;

        case("add"):
            // add the 2nd parameter
            editMessageText($chatId, $messageId, "should I add?");
            break;

        default:
            sendMessage($chatId, "default");
    }

    function sendMessage($chatId, $message) {
        $url = $GLOBALS[website]."/sendMessage?    chat_id=".$chatId."&text=".urlencode($message)."&reply_markup".$reply1;
        file_get_contents($url);
    }

    function editMessageText($chatId, $messageId, $message) {
        $url = $GLOBALS[website]."/editMessageText?chat_id=".$chatId."&message_id=".$messageId."&text=".urlencode($message);
        file_get_contents($url);
    }

    function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);       

        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        return $data;
    }
?>
```

I tried to use this as a example and its not work if I use this its keep loading and after a minute the bot will spam me with the same amount of button i press with him

I already used above code but its not editing it incase its sending me the same message

Comment: Please make sure your title summarizes your question, it should not read like an opening message on a chat channel.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add break inside default

```
default:
        sendMessage($chatId, "default");
        break;
}
```

I capture this one I think it is also getting some error, you did not assign any value to variable $reply1, and also missing = mark after the &reply_markup

```
function sendMessage($chatId, $message) {
    $url = $GLOBALS[website]."/sendMessage?chat_id=".$chatId."&text=".urlencode($message)."&reply_markup".$reply1;
    file_get_contents($url);
}
```

if you need to run for the testing use this

```
function sendMessage($chatId, $message) {
    $url = $GLOBALS[website]."/sendMessage?chat_id=".$chatId."&text=".urlencode($message);
    file_get_contents($url);
}
```

[If you need any help](https://youtu.be/vDeM-9KGUnk)